# How to get payment terms data from QuickBooks

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc, com-object

I am using COM objects to integrate QuickBooks data to my application. I am able to get paymentmethod using IPaymentMethodRetList.

Like :

```
IPaymentMethodQuery CustQ = requestSet.AppendPaymentMethodQueryRq();
IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestSet);


_QBPaymentMethodRet = default(IPaymentMethodRet);
_QBPaymentMethodList = default(IPaymentMethodRetList);

IResponse response = responseSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
if ((response.Detail != null))
{
    _QBPaymentMethodList = (IPaymentMethodRetList)response.Detail;

    if (_QBPaymentMethodList != null)
    {   ----------------------------
        --------------------
    }
```

But I'm unable to find the interface for payment terms. Which interface do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the QuickBooks OSR for documentation on this:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Payment Methods in QuickBooks *are NOT* the same thing as Terms. *Payment Methods* are actual methods of payment (e.g. Visa, MasterCard, Check, etc.), while *Terms* are sales terms (e.g. Net 30, Net 60, Due on Receipt, etc.).

If you want *Payment Methods* then you need to do a `PaymentMethodQueryRq`. If you want *Terms* then you need to do a `TermsQueryRq`.